# Problems converting TSQL to LINQ MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, t-sql

This is my working TSQL. I'm struggling trying to convert this into LINQ and have results in a collection. Many thanks in advance

```
select  p.CoreSPID as SPID,
  sum(case when pp.PricingCategory = 'Water' and pp.WholesalePricing=0 then pp.FixedCharge end) RetailWaterFixed,sum(case when pp.PricingCategory = 'Water' and pp.WholesalePricing=0 then pp.VolumetricCharge end) RetailWaterVar
from PremisePricings pp,Premises p
and p.PremiseId = pp.PremiseId 
group by p.CoreSPID

UNION

select  p.CoreSPID as SPID,
  sum(case when pp.PricingCategory = 'Water' and pp.WholesalePricing=0 then pp.FixedCharge end) RetailWaterFixed,sum(case when pp.PricingCategory = 'Water' and pp.WholesalePricing=0 then pp.VolumetricCharge end) RetailWaterVar
from PremiseMeteredPricings pp,Premises p,PremiseMeters pm
and p.PremiseId = pm.PremiseId and pm.PremiseMeterId = pp.PremiseMeterId
group by p.CoreSPID
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but i'm using EF6 code first MVC5 and just wanted to see how to run the same query in LINQ syntax. Group and a UNION going on

Answer (score 0):

If you have any control over the database, the easiest solution is to use a view:

1. Create view based on your provided SQL code from the question
2. Import the view into your entity model
3. Use the new entity model to transform the elements into a list

Your code may then look something like this:

```
List<AllPricing> list = db.AllPricings.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       var uniondemo = (from p in dc. PremisePricings
              select new { Filename = p.filename, Size = p.size }).Union(
              from k in dc. PremisePricings2
              select new ({SPID=p.CoreSPID })
             .sum(case when pp.PricingCategory = 'Water' and pp.WholesalePricing=0 then

      pp.FixedCharge end) as RetailWaterFixed,sum(case when pp.PricingCategory = 'Water' and 

      pp.WholesalePricing=0 then pp.VolumetricCharge end) as VolumetricCharge  ;
```

Comment: Thanks Jason I tried to make this approach work but could not, the syntax was erronous and was taking long time to try to correct not knowing if its going to work. Now trying to call stored procedure